# Hiding Ribbon Tab when no visible button on it

Tags: ms-access, ribbon

I'm developing a multi-user application with access as a front-end, using a custom ribbon to retrieve functionalities. I'm an intermediate VBA developer, but with little experience on XML ribbons.

Well, the scenario: I have a table that relates users with forms to define permissions, when my Users Log In, I run through that table and write an array with the permissions for the current user. All my ribbon buttons have the GetVisible="GetVisibleCallback", so when the ribbon gets invalidated, the callback checks against the array to hide/unhide the buttons, with the code:

```
Public Sub GetVisibleCallback(control As IRibbonControl, ByRef visible As Variant)
If IsEmpty(arrayPermissoes) Then
    visible = False
Else
    If UBound(Filter(arrayPermissoes, control.Tag)) > -1 Then
        visible = True
    Else
        visible = False
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

This is working flawleslly, but the problem is: I have multiple tabs on the custom ribbon, and some users has no permission for any form on a determined tab eg.: "Register Tabs", when the Ribbon gets invalidated, the users can see the tab, but it has no Buttons in it. What I would like to achieve is: If there is no visible button on a determined tab, make it invisible too, how can I achieve this?

Sorry for the Bad English! I'm working on it!

Answer (score 0):

The `tab` control provides the `getVisible` callback. So, you can check whether a user is allowed to see it or not. Also you may consider calling the `Invalidate` method of the `IRibbonUI` interface which allows to invalidate the cached values for all of the controls of the Ribbon user interface.

You can customize the Ribbon UI by using callback procedures. For each of the callbacks implemented, the responses are cached. For example, if a solution writer implements the `getImage` callback procedure for a button, the function is called once, the image loads, and then if the image needs to be updated, the cached image is used instead of recalling the procedure. This process remains in-place until the code signals that the cached values are invalid by using the `Invalidate` method, at which time, the callback procedure is again called and the return response is cached.

```
 <customUI … OnLoad="MyAddinInitialize" …>
```

…

```
  Dim MyRibbon As IRibbonUI 

  Sub MyAddInInitialize(Ribbon As IRibbonUI) 
    Set MyRibbon = Ribbon 
  End Sub 

  Sub myFunction() 
    MyRibbon.Invalidate() ' Invalidates the caches of all of this add-in's controls 
  End Sub
```

Read more about the Fluent UI (aka Ribbon UI) in the following series of articles:

- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 1 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338202(v=office.12))
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 2 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa338199(v%3Doffice.12))
- [Customizing the 2007 Office Fluent Ribbon for Developers (Part 3 of 3)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/office-2007/aa722523(v%3Doffice.12))